# Create a rewrite for categories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

the goal is to rewrite Mysite.com.au/base/2ndbase/3rdbase/4thbase to mysite.com.au/2ndbase/3rdbase/5thbase.

looking to add it as a function in the functions.php

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^3rdbase/4thbase/?','/5thbase/?','top');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I can not find any posts that point me to the basic no query just rewrite the URL using the add_rewrite rule

I assumed that this would be simple but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Have you flushed the permalinks in Wordpress? You should do so after doing any custom route changes. wp-admin > settings > permalinks > save

Comment: Hello Thank you for that, I just tried the flush to test again and unfortunately, this still didn't work.